# Inline Entity Form validation

Tags: 8, forms, taxonomy-terms

Created a content type and add taxonomy form in it using [Inline entity Form module](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form).

So, the rendered taxonomy add term looks like :

[image]

What I want to do is **ADD CUSTOM VALIDATION** to the "**NAME**" field.

I tried:

```
function hook_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter(&$entity_form, &$form_state) {
  //kint($form_state->getStorage('inline_entity_form'));die;
  // $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  //   $nid = $entity->get('name')->getValue();
  $userInput = $form_state->getUserInput();
 // kint($form_state->getUserInput()['field_plan_features']['form']['inline_entity_form']['name']);die;
 // $form_state->setErrorByName('name', t('Term already exists in taxonomy blah'));
}
```

How it can be done.. please suggest some way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you implement hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) function.

```
    function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
      // Check if the $form_id is your node type add form.
             if ($form_id == 'article') {
                // Add a custom validation function. Example:
                $form['#validate'][] = 'custom_form_test';
              }
    }
```

Then you need to implement the custom function where you will put your logic.

```
function custom_form_test(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Get value of the field which use the inline entity form display.
 $tags_value = $form_state->getValue('field_tags');

}
```

See the screenshot of the $form_state dump and also with the field_tags taxonomy term reference values:
[image]

So you can access all the values from the inline form display.
For example to access name value:

```
$name = $tags_value[0]['inline_entity_form']['name'][0]['value'];
```

Just looping into arrays. Once you get the value that you want you cand restrict finishing the submision of a node by write a message error. Example:

```
 $form_state->setErrorByName(
                'field_tags',
                'The name is WRONG!'
              );
```

Hope to help you!